# Can any one provide elastic search Query equivalent to the SQL

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, nosql

```
update Customers 
set name = "bob" 
where email like "%@gmail.com"
```

I am trying to update all documents columns with some value based on the column that ends with the given string pattern.

Customers is the `table_name`. I am trying to update name value to bob based on the email ending with `@gmail.com`.

Comment: Have you studied the docs? What have you tried so far? Do you know update by query feature?

Comment: @ibexit  thanks for responding . I had gone through docs and know about the update by query feature. But I am unable to find how to write like operator (regex kind of thing ) elastic search. if you can please help me

Comment: for regex kind of queries, you might want to have a look at wildcard queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html